# Issue in running generated build using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, selenium-webdriver

I have prepared a testing framework using selenium webdriver.

It uses testng to generate test results.

Now when I run the Build.xml file then it shows that build is successful, but when try to execute the build it fails and shows a msg it does not contain main class.

After that I added a main class in my project, it works and I was able to execute the jar file.

The issue is only the main class gets executed and not the whole project.

In order to resolve it I added instances of all the classes in main class and it worked.

But my main issue is the Test Results.
It is not generating test result using Testng.

Can any one help me out?

Comment: Could you post the complete message you see when *"the build fails and shows a msg it does not contain main class"*

Comment: The Build does not fails but when I tried to run the jar build through cmd it shows a msg that it does not contain main class.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using ant, take a look at the following it should give you a good idea of what you need to do

http://openwritings.net/public/testng/ant-build-file-testng

Of course that's just to run testng, before that in your build.xml file I recommend that you clean and compile all your classes.

This is also a good example of build.xml to compile and run your program using testng

http://www.seleniumtests.com/2011/06/selenium-tutorial-ant-build-for.html